# What is the meaning of n_live_tup and n_dead_tup in pg_stat_user_tables

Tags: postgresql

What is the meaning of `n_live_tup` and `n_dead_tup` in `pg_stat_user_tables` or `pgstattuple`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Those two columns are the result of

```
SELECT pg_stat_get_live_tuples(c.oid) AS n_live_tup
     , pg_stat_get_dead_tuples(c.oid) AS n_dead_tup
FROM   pg_class c;
```

Representing the number of live and dead rows (tuples) in the table.
Find those [functions in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-FUNCS-TABLE).

Dead rows are deleted rows that will later be reused for new rows from `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s (the space, not the data). Some dead rows (or reserved free space) can be particularly useful for HOT updates (Heap-Only Tuples) that can reuse space in the same data page efficiently. More on H.O.T.:

- [PostgreSQL Initial Database Size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21014/postgresql-initial-database-size/21507#21507)
- [Release notes for PostgreSQL 8.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/release-8-3.html#AEN88352) where this feature was introduced.

Dead rows can be removed by `VACUUM FULL` (or plain `VACUUM` if it gets lucky) or similar operations on the table, thereby shrinking the physical size accordingly.

Whenever a row is deleted or updated, the old row version becomes invisible to all other transactions starting after the transaction has been committed - with default [`READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html). The row is completely dead as soon as there are no more uncommitted older transactions. That is necessary for [PostgreSQL's MVCC model](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) to handle concurrency.

Those are just *statistics*. You need to enable statistics collection in `postgresql.conf` if you want them to be updated automatically. `track_counts` should be on by default, though. Bear in mind that statistics are not updated instantaneously.
More about the statistics collector in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html).

Comment: What is Heap-Only Tuples? When I issue `SELECT n_live_tup FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHEN relname = 'mytable';` Why it shows zero? `mytable` has 6 rows.

Comment: @MajidAzimi: I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: @MajidAzimi If you want to learn a bunch about MVCC and HoT check out the slides from [Pavan Deolasee's presentation at PGCon'08](http://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/events/105.en.html)

Comment: @dbenhur: Nice link! The presentation is very well done and easy to understand.

Comment: @dbenhur The link seems to be dead now.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog Really?  I just clicked it and it brings up the presentation synopsis page with a link to a 1.6MB PowerPoint file.