# Approaches for deleting unnecessary records from tables

Tags: postgresql, delete, truncate

We have a database which stores the temperatures of 20 thermometer every 7 seconds. We want to delete all records in the way that every minute holds just one tempereature instead of 8 which are older than 3 months. I was planning to do it as follows as discussed in that question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42429/truncate-or-delete-vacuum-full-for-deleting-some-of-the-table-rows/42433?noredirect=1#42433):

1. Select the (relatively few) surviving rows into a temporary table.
2. Truncate the table.
3. Re-insert the survivors.

But all devices are working without interruption and inserting values into the DB so I can not Truncate and rename the temp_tables since the system should be on all the time. Or can I? If not, do I have to do it by DELETE VACUUM?

By the way we delete all unnecessary records which are older than 3 months just once, afterwards we have to repeat this process every month for the 4.th month previous (I hope that part was clear). If we repeat this process at the beginning of 05.2013, we have to delete the unnecessary records of the month 01.2013. How can I automatize this process? Should I better write a .bat file for scheduled task or is there any better approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misinterpreting a part of [my advice to your previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42429/truncate-or-delete-vacuum-full-for-deleting-some-of-the-table-rows/42433#42433):

> so I can not Truncate and rename the temp_tables since the system
>   should be on all the time.

There was no renaming involved. After `TRUNCATE` you run an `INSERT`. The only *blocking* operation is the `TRUNCATE`. [I quote the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-truncate.html):

> `TRUNCATE` acquires an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on each table it
>   operates on, which blocks all other concurrent operations on the
>   table.  (...) If concurrent access to a table is required, then the
>   `DELETE` command should be used instead.

`INSERT` may still work, if it is not time-critical and allowed to wait until the lock is released. `TRUNCATE` is usually very fast, if you run it in a separate transaction, it should only block for a couple of milliseconds. Note: separate transaction, not separate session! Your temporary table lives and dies with the session.

The drawback of a separate transaction: if you lose your session before you are able to re-insert from the temporary table, you loose data. To be sure, you could use a plain table instead. (Which would offer the alternative path to drop the old and rename the new table.)

Either way, your updated question makes clear that you want to run this repeatedly, accumulating old rows in the same table. In this case, `TRUNCATE` is not a good option anyway. You can always just use a plain `DELETE`. Considerably slower with big tables, but concurrent `INSERT` is not blocked at all. The autovacuuming daemon will have to do some more work, too.

It's mostly a trade-off between speed and security.

#### SQL

The `DELETE` command for the slow and sure method could look like this:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE tbl t
USING (
   SELECT created_at FROM tbl WHERE created_at < now() - (interval '3 month')
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT min(created_at) AS created_at
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY date_trunc('minute', created_at)
   WHERE  created_at < now() - (interval '3 month')
   ) x USING (created_at)
WHERE  x.created_at IS NULL
AND    d.created_at = t.created_at;
```

Comment: You have answered all my open questions as if you were reading my mind thanks = )

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you another approach/solution. You can partition the table and delete partition older than 3 months just dropping them. This is fast and does not impact other inserts.
However seems that you need to keep at least one value; can you calculate values to be kept and insert them in another table?

Comment: yes I can do that actually, do you mean, I split each table into 2 partition as older than 3months and last 3months, select the values to be kept, insert into temp_table, delete the partition older than 3months and insert the survival values again into the table?

Comment: @mctuna No. I mean to redef the current table into a partition table by month (this cannot be done online sorry). Then for old data, summarise them and move to another table and drop the old month partition. This speed up any DML on the table. I do not think you can insert the sum'ed values into the same table unless you are able to keep the same data structure. Partition strategy is the definite solution to bulk DML. Sorry that postgre does not support online redef like dbms_redefinition in oracle.