# Managing and speeding up queries on PostgreSQL table with over 3 trillion rows

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, partitioning, database-recommendation

I have time series data which spans over 10 years and has over 3 trillion rows and 10 columns.

At the moment I use a PCIe SSD with 128GB of RAM and I am finding that querying takes a significant amount of time. For example running the below command takes well over 15 mins:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE column_a = 'value1' AND column_b = 'value2';
```

The table is mostly used for reads. The only time the table is written to is during weekly updates which insert about 15 million rows.

What are the best ways to manage tables so large? Would you recommend splitting it by year?

The table size is 542 GB and the external size is 109 GB.

`EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` output:

```
"Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..116820941.44 rows=758 width=92) (actual time=0.011..1100643.844 rows=667 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (("COLUMN_A" = 'Value1'::text) AND ("COLUMN_B" = 'Value2'::text))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 4121893840"
"  Buffers: shared hit=2 read=56640470 dirtied=476248 written=476216"
"Total runtime: 1100643.967 ms"
```

The table was created using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  DATE     timestamp with time zone,
  COLUMN_A text,
  COLUMN_B text,
  VALUE_1  double precision,
  VALUE_2  double precision,
  VALUE_3  double precision,
  VALUE_4  double precision,
  VALUE_5  double precision,
  VALUE_6  double precision,
  VALUE_7  double precision,
);

CREATE INDEX ix_table_name_date ON table_name (DATE);
```

Comment: This is nearly information-free. Table sizes? What is "a significant amount of time"? `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` output? Mostly read-only, or a fair read/write mix? How much RAM on the system? Please edit the question and comment here when done.

Comment: I suggest you add the `CREATE TABLE` statement as well and any indexes that you have on the table.

Comment: Are the queries CPU-bound? Or I/O bound? Look at 'top' for cpu and iowait. Also, query patterns. Do you look at a lot of different combos  of these columns or mostly query a few combinations?

Comment: Top shows iowait values less then 1.0 when running the query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your existing index on `DATE` is obviously useless for the query. The first obvious step for your query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE column_a = 'value1' AND column_b = 'value2';
```

is an **index** for `column_a` or `column_b` (which ever is more selective) or possibly a multicolumn index on `(column_a, column_b)`, like:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_a_b_idx ON tbl(column_a, column_b);
```

Details:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Next, I would consider partial indexes if you can safely exclude large parts of the table from the queries. Or partition your table in something like 100 partitions. And use [constraint exclusion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.htm#DDL-PARTITIONING-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION).

"Splitting it by year", like you contemplated, would be just as useless (harmful, even) as your index on `DATE` for the given query. Partitions need to be based on columns in the predicates of the query (`column_a` and `column_b`) to be helpful. Predicates on just *one* column would be much easier in this respect. If you have important queries filtering on various columns, partitioning is probably not the way to go. (Partial indexes still might.)

If partitioning is no good, a less invasive measure would be to `CLUSTER` data based on the new index (you can't use a partial index for this). Or simply create a new table from the sorted output of a query. This is particularly interesting since your table is mostly read-only. It should pay to do this at least *once*, but that one time will be very expensive: the whole table has to be re-written one or the other way. You need enough free space, as much RAM as you can get and an exclusive lock on the table. Or use `pg_repack`, to avoid the exclusive lock:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)
- [Best way to populate a new column in a large table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52517/best-way-to-populate-a-new-column-in-a-large-table/52531#52531)

Be sure to run the latest version of Postgres. The upcoming **Postgres 9.5** might be particularly interesting for you, since it introduces [**BRIN indexes**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/brin.html) (block range indexes), which can reduce the index size dramatically for very big tables. Might be exactly what you are looking for.