# How to handle bad query plan caused by exact equality on range type?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, range-types, query-performance

I'm performing an update where I require an exact equality on a `tstzrange` variable. ~1M rows are modified, and the query takes ~13 minutes. The result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` can be seen [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/4pd5), and the actual results are extremely different from those estimated by the query planner. The problem is that the index scan on `t_range` expects a single row to be returned.

This seems to be related to the fact that statistics on range types are stored differently from those of other types. Looking at the `pg_stats` view for the column, `n_distinct` is -1 and other fields (e.g. `most_common_vals`, `most_common_freqs`) are empty.

However, there must be statistics stored on `t_range` somewhere. An extremely similar update where I use a 'within' on t_range instead of an exact equality takes about 4 minutes to perform, and uses a substantially different query plan (see [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/qU9G)). The second query plan makes sense to me because every row in the temp table and a substantial fraction of the history table will be used. More importantly, the query planner predicts an approximately correct number of rows for the filter on `t_range`.

The distribution of `t_range` is a bit unusual. I'm using this table to store the historical state of another table, and the changes to the other table occur all at once in big dumps, so there aren't many distinct values of `t_range`. Here are the counts corresponding to each of the unique values of `t_range`:

```
                              t_range                              |  count  
-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------
 ["2014-06-12 20:58:21.447478+00","2014-06-27 07:00:00+00")        |  994676
 ["2014-06-12 20:58:21.447478+00","2014-08-01 01:22:14.621887+00") |   36791
 ["2014-06-27 07:00:00+00","2014-08-01 07:00:01+00")               | 1000403
 ["2014-06-27 07:00:00+00",infinity)                               |   36791
 ["2014-08-01 07:00:01+00",infinity)                               |  999753
```

The counts for distinct `t_range` above are complete, so the cardinality is ~3M (of which ~1M will be affected by either update query).

Why does query 1 perform much more poorly than query 2? In my case, query 2 is a good substitute, but if an exact range equality was truly required, how could I get Postgres to use a smarter query plan?

**Table definition** with indexes (dropping irrelevant columns):

```
       Column        |   Type    |                                  Modifiers                                   
---------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 history_id          | integer   | not null default nextval('gtfs_stop_times_history_history_id_seq'::regclass)
 t_range             | tstzrange | not null
 trip_id             | text      | not null
 stop_sequence       | integer   | not null
 shape_dist_traveled | real      | 
Indexes:
    "gtfs_stop_times_history_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (history_id)
    "gtfs_stop_times_history_t_range" gist (t_range)
    "gtfs_stop_times_history_trip_id" btree (trip_id)
```

**Query 1:**

```
UPDATE gtfs_stop_times_history sth
SET shape_dist_traveled = tt.shape_dist_traveled
FROM gtfs_stop_times_temp tt
WHERE sth.trip_id = tt.trip_id
AND sth.stop_sequence = tt.stop_sequence
AND sth.t_range = '["2014-08-01 07:00:01+00",infinity)'::tstzrange;
```

**Query 2:**

```
UPDATE gtfs_stop_times_history sth
SET shape_dist_traveled = tt.shape_dist_traveled
FROM gtfs_stop_times_temp tt
WHERE sth.trip_id = tt.trip_id
AND sth.stop_sequence = tt.stop_sequence
AND '2014-08-01 07:00:01+00'::timestamptz <@ sth.t_range;
```

Q1 updates 999753 rows and Q2 updates 999753+36791 = 1036544 (ie, the temp table is such that every row matching the time range condition is updated).

I tried this query in response to [@ypercube's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73361/how-to-handle-bad-query-plan-caused-by-exact-equality-on-range-type/127986#comment132112_73361):

**Query 3:**

```
UPDATE gtfs_stop_times_history sth
SET shape_dist_traveled = tt.shape_dist_traveled
FROM gtfs_stop_times_temp tt
WHERE sth.trip_id = tt.trip_id
AND sth.stop_sequence = tt.stop_sequence
AND sth.t_range <@ '["2014-08-01 07:00:01+00",infinity)'::tstzrange
AND '["2014-08-01 07:00:01+00",infinity)'::tstzrange <@ sth.t_range;
```

The query plan and results (see [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/VhO4)) were intermediate between the two previous cases (~6 minutes).

**2016/02/05 EDIT**

No longer having access to the data after 1.5 years, I created a test table with the same structure (with no indexes) and similar cardinality. [jjanes's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128065/45147) proposed that the cause might be the ordering of the temporary table used for the update. I was unable to test the hypothesis directly because I don't have access to `track_io_timing` (using Amazon RDS).

1. The overall results were much faster (by a factor of several). I'm guessing that this is because of the removal of the indices, consistent with [Erwin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127986/45147).
2. In this test case, Queries 1 and 2 basically took the same amount of time, because they both used the merge join. That is, I was unable to trigger whatever was causing Postgres to choose the hash join, so I have no clarity on why Postgres was choosing the poorly-performing hash join in the first place.

Comment: What if you converted the equality condition `(a = b)` to two "contains" conditions: `(a @> b AND b @> a)`? Does the plan change?

Comment: @ypercube: the plan changes substantially, though it still isn't quite optimal -- see my edit #2.

Comment: Another idea would be to add a regular btree index on `(lower(t_range),upper(t_range))` since you check on equality.

Answer (score 9):

The biggest difference in time in your execution plans is on the top node, the UPDATE itself.  This suggests that most of your time is going to IO during the update.  You could verify this by turning on `track_io_timing` and running the queries with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

The different plans are presenting rows to be updated in different orders.  One is in `trip_id` order, and the other is in whichever order they happen to be physically present in in the temp table.

The table being updated seems to have its physical order correlated with the trip_id column, and updating rows in this order leads to efficient IO patterns with read-ahead/sequential reads.  While the physical order of the temp table seems to lead to a lot of random reads.

If you can add an `order by trip_id` to the statement which created the temp table, that might solve the problem for you.

PostgreSQL does not take the effects of IO ordering into account when planning the UPDATE operation.  (Unlike SELECT operations, where it does take them into account).  If PostgreSQL were cleverer, it would either realize that one plan produces a more efficient order, or it would interject an explicit sort node between the update and its child node so that the update would get fed rows in ctid order.

You are correct that PostgreSQL does a poor job estimating the selectivity of equality joins on ranges.  However, this is only tangentially related to your fundamental problem.  A more efficient query on the select portion of your update might accidentally happen to feed rows into the update-proper in a better order, but if so that is mostly down to luck.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to modify `track_io_timing`, and (since it has been a year and a half!) I no longer have access to the original data. However, I tested your theory by creating tables with the same schema and similar size (millions of rows), and running two different updates -- one in which the temp update table was sorted like the original table, and another in which it was sorted quasi-randomly. Unfortunately, the two updates take roughly the same amount of time, implying that the ordering of the update table doesn't affect this query.

Answer (score 7):

I am not exactly sure why the selectivity of an equality predicate is so radically over-estimated by the GiST index on the `tstzrange` column. While that remains interesting per se, it seems irrelevant to your particular case.

Since your `UPDATE` modifies one third (!) of all existing 3M rows, ***an index is not going to help at all***. On the contrary, incrementally updating the index in addition to the table is going to add substantial cost to your `UPDATE`.

Just keep your simple **Query 1**. The simple, radical **solution** is to **drop the index** before the `UPDATE`. If you need it for other purposes, re-create it after the `UPDATE`. This would still be faster than maintaining the index during the large `UPDATE`.

For an `UPDATE` on a third of all rows, it will probably pay to drop all other indexes as well - and re-create them after the `UPDATE`. The only downside: you need additional privileges and an exclusive lock on the table (only for a brief moment if you use [`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY)).

[@ypercube's idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73361/how-to-handle-bad-query-plan-caused-by-exact-equality-on-range-type#comment132323_73361) to use a btree instead of the GiST index seems good in principal. But *not* for one third of all rows (where no index is any good to begin with), and *not* on just `(lower(t_range),upper(t_range))`, since `tstzrange` in not a discrete range type.

Most discrete range types have a canonical form, which makes the concept of "equality" simpler: lower and upper bound of the value in canonical form define it. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE)

> A discrete range type should have a *canonicalization* function that is
>   aware of the desired step size for the element type. The
>   canonicalization function is charged with converting equivalent values
>   of the range type to have identical representations, in particular
>   consistently inclusive or exclusive bounds. If a canonicalization
>   function is not specified, then ranges with different formatting will
>   always be treated as unequal, even though they might represent the
>   same set of values in reality.
>
> The built-in range types `int4range`, `int8range`, and `daterange` all use a
>   canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper
>   bound; that is, `[)`. User-defined range types can use other
>   conventions, however.

This is not the case for `tstzrange`, where inclusivity of upper and lower bound need to be considered for equality. A possible btree index would have to be on:

```
(lower(t_range), upper(t_range), lower_inc(t_range), upper_inc(t_range))
```

And the queries would have to use the same expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

One might be tempted to just index the whole value cast to `text`: <strike>`(cast(t_range AS text))`</strike> - but this expression is not `IMMUTABLE` since the text representation of `timestamptz` values depends on the current `timezone` setting. You would need to put additional steps into an `IMMUTABLE` wrapper function that produces a canonical form, and create a functional index on that ...

#### Additional measures / alternative ideas

If `shape_dist_traveled` can already have the same value as `tt.shape_dist_traveled` for more than a few of your updated rows (and you don't rely on any side effects of your `UPDATE` like triggers ...), you can make your query faster by excluding empty updates:

```
WHERE ...
AND   shape_dist_traveled IS DISTINCT FROM tt.shape_dist_traveled;
```

- [Does updating a row with the same value actually update the row?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118178/does-updating-a-row-with-the-same-value-actually-update-the-row/118214#118214)

Of course, all general advice for performance optimization applies. [The Postgres Wiki is a good starting point.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)

`VACUUM FULL` would be poison for you, since some dead tuples (or space reserved by `FILLFACTOR`) is beneficial for `UPDATE` performance.

With that many updated rows, and if you can afford it (no concurrent access or other dependencies), it might be even faster to write a completely new table instead of updating in place. Instructions in this related answer:

- [Optimizing bulk update performance in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41059/optimizing-bulk-update-performance-in-postgresql/41111#41111)