# Sort table rows and save the row numbers using UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, performance, update, window-functions, query-performance

I have Postgres 9.5 with a table `movimientos` that has the following data:

```
| id | concepto | movimiento | numero | orden |
|  1 | AJUSTE 1 |       2542 |      0 |     2 |
|  2 | APERTURA |      12541 |      0 |     1 |
|  3 | AJUSTE 2 |       2642 |      0 |     2 |
|  4 | CIERRE   |      22642 |      0 |     3 |
```

And I need to number the records based on the `orden` field and keep these numbers in the `numero` field, because I need this data to sort and search by `numero` in reports. Example:

```
| id | concepto | movimiento | numero | orden |
|  2 | APERTURA |      12541 |      1 |     1 |
|  1 | AJUSTE 1 |       2542 |      2 |     2 |
|  3 | AJUSTE 2 |       2642 |      3 |     2 |
|  4 | CIERRE   |      22642 |      4 |     3 |
```

I tried to do it using a function with a `FOR` but is very slow with a million rows.

How to do this using a simple `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Join to a subquery that computes `numero` with the [window function `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```
UPDATE movimientos m
SET    numero = sub.rn
FROM  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY orden, id) AS rn FROM movimientos) sub
WHERE  m.id = sub.id;
```

Details for [`UPDATE` syntax in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

If you have concurrent write access you need to lock the table to avoid race conditions.

Note that updating *every* row in a table is expensive either way. The table typically grows to twice its size and `VACUUM` or `VACUUM FULL` may be in order.

Depending on your complete situation it *may* be more efficient to write a new table to begin with. Related answers with instructions:

- [Best way to populate a new column in a large table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52517/best-way-to-populate-a-new-column-in-a-large-table/52531#52531)
- [Optimizing bulk update performance in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41059/optimizing-bulk-update-performance-in-postgresql/41111#41111)

I am not convinced, though, that you need the column `numero` in your table *at all*. Maybe you are looking for a [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html). Recent related answer on SO:

- [Global row numbers in chunked query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36983384/939860)