# Performance hickups after Postgres 9.4 upgrade

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.4, fill-factor, auto-growth

After upgrading our database from 9.3.5 to 9.4.1 last night, the server suffers from high CPU spikes. The upgrade was done with pg_dump.  So the database was converted to SQL and then imported into 9.4.

During the CPU spikes, there are a lot of these messages in the logs:

```
process X still waiting for ExclusiveLock on extension of relation Y of database Z 
after 1036.234 ms
```

And:

```
process X acquired ExclusiveLock on extension of relation Y of database Z
after 2788.050 ms
```

What looks suspicious is that there are sometimes several "acquired" messages for the exact same relation number in the exact same millisecond.

Why would Postgres grow a table twice in the same millisecond? Could it be an index with a high fill factor?

Any suggestions on how to approach this issue are welcome.

P.S. I've also [asked this question on the Postgres mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/55301A8E.8040005@aule.net#55301A8E.8040005@aule.net), if that's not okay let me know.

Comment: X-post to mailing list is ok. But please add the link. I found it and there is a good answer already: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/55301A8E.8040005@aule.net#55301A8E.8040005@aule.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem had to do with a kernel feature called Transparent Huge Pages (THP.)  You can diagnose this with `perf top`:

```
 59.73%       postmaster  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] compaction_alloc
  1.31%       postmaster  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] _spin_lock
  0.94%       postmaster  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] __reset_isolation_suitable
  0.78%       postmaster  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] compact_zone
  0.67%       postmaster  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] get_pageblock_flags_group
  0.64%       postmaster  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] copy_page_c
  0.48%           :13410  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] compaction_alloc
  0.45%           :13465  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] compaction_alloc
  0.45%       postmaster  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] clear_page_c
  0.44%       postmaster  postgres               [.] hash_search_with_hash_value
  0.41%           :13324  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] compaction_alloc
  0.40%           :13561  [kernel.kallsyms]      [k] compaction_alloc
```

The `compaction_alloc` function points at a problem.  You can turn off THP with:

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Postgres versions before 9.4 do not specifically ask for huge pages, but it can be forced on them with `always`.

[Here's a link to RedHat discouraging THP for database workloads.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-memory-transhuge.html)

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't have guessed.

Comment: @andomar : we had the same problems as You had. Will turn off THP resolve the issue ? How about the effects to any other things ? Thanks.

Comment: @SoniHarriz: Worked for us, you can try it out, the change is effective without a reboot or restarting postgres. We noticed no negative side effects.

Comment: I'll be damned! This is probably what is killing performance on my servers after the upgrade. Do you know by chance the corresponding configuration on ubuntu/debian? I found the following (sysctl -a | grep huge): vm.hugepages_treat_as_movable = 0, vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0, vm.nr_hugepages = 0, vm.nr_hugepages_mempolicy = 0, vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0

Comment: @cherio: http://askubuntu.com/questions/597372/how-do-i-modify-sys-kernel-mm-transparent-hugepage-enabled

Answer (score 2):

A dump-restore cycle removes all bloat and dead tuples from your tables and restores with the minimum possible size - except if you have a [`fillfactor`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) setting below 100 that reserves some wiggle-room per data page.

Immediately after the migration, you get *a lot* more "extensions" (added pages at the physical end of the table (the file on disk).

The pro-active solution would be to set a **`fillfactor` below 100** on tables with lots of random updates. You can do that in the dump ***before*** you restore again. Since you are already through with the migration, you might just wait for the dust to settle. Typically, extensions become less frequent while wiggle-room is reintroduced with dead row versions in your updated tables.

For tables with lots of random updates it might be a good idea to set `FILLFACTOR` below 100 in any case. Applies to btree indexes in a similar fashion. But the reserved space is only added to existing data pages with a `VACUUM FULL` or `CLUSTER` (or a dump-restore cycle).

More on `FILLFACTOR`, updates and `VACUUM`:

- [What fillfactor for caching table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36383/what-fillfactor-for-caching-table/36443#36443)
- [PostgreSQL Initial Database Size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21014/postgresql-initial-database-size/21507#21507)
- [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/are-regular-vacuum-analyze-stil-recommended-under-9-1/18694#18694)

Comment: Thanks. An extension doesn't seem like a CPU intensive operation... any idea on how an extension could cause high CPU load?

Comment: @Andomar: That's a bit of a surprise to me, too. I can only speculate about possible side effect of lock contention in the process. [From what I read](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20150329185619.GA29062@alap3.anarazel.de#20150329185619.GA29062@alap3.anarazel.de), efforts are made to improve things for Postgres 9.5

Comment: Turns out the extension locks were just a manifestation of a problem with transparent huge pages. From what I read, setting a manual fillfactor only helps with HOT (heap only tuple) workloads. That's rather uncommon.